# Перетаскивание текста на элементе Canvas с помощью jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, canvas, html5

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли к тексту, который уже нарисованный (отрендеренный) на элементе Canvas применить jQuery UI drag & drop (http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/), чтобы текст можно было перетаскивать по холсту Canvas? Подобному тому как это делается с помощью Flash. Или как можно реализовать такой эффект (другим способом, без помощи jQuery и jQuery UI)? Буду очень благодарен всем, кто откликнется мне помочь с решением данной проблемы.

Comment: [Thoughts on when to use Canvas and SVG][1]

> Canvas - Single HTML element similar to <img> in behavior.

[1]:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/04/22/thoughts-on-when-to-use-canvas-and-svg.aspx

Comment: Чтобы использовать эффект jQuery UI draggable нужно использовать вместо Canvas - SVG? Я правильно понял?

Comment: Типа того. [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html). Есть еще вариант [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Comment: Ппц, придется все переделывать.. Печально!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После отрисовки текста на холсте Canvas дальнейшие манипуляции с ним уже невозможны. Можно только заново перерисовывать текст на холсте поверх старого теста. Нужно либо так и делать, либо работать с HTML DOM или SVG DOM.

Comment: Я тоже так думал, что после отрисовки текста на холсте Canvas дальнейшие манипуляции с ним уже невозможны, пока не прочел книгу  HTML5 Canvas Steve Fulton & Jeff Fulton (http://book.tr200.net/v.php?id=1136162)